# dynamic footer kohana v3

Tags: kohana-3

I've been able to render the footer view (e.g: View::factory('pages/footer'), but I would like this view for example to be managed by a controller class within the main controller.

Imagine:
main template controller (common to all pages)
   dynamic header controller class
   dynamic menu controller class
   dynamic foooter controller class

Thanks,
for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
// in your View
echo Request->factory('layout/footer')->execute()->response;
```

It will execute (by default) `Controller_Layout::action_footer()`.